# Does the SignalR IHubProxy interface expose any properties that indicate that the client is in a disconnected state?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I have a .NET client that creates a proxy to my hub class. When the server hosting that hub goes down for long enough, the client will go into a disconnected state. I want to check if the proxy is in a disconnected state before invoking a hub method, rather than just attempting to invoke the hub method and then catching the error if it's in a disconnected state.

While debugging in Visual Studio I can see the `IHubProxy` object has a base property `State` indicating the current state. It says Connected when it's working fine, and it says Disconnected when it's disconnected. However, I can't seem to access this property.

Does anyone know if there is a way to tell? Ideally I'd just like to do something like this:

```
if (hubProxy.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
{
    this.AttemptReconnection();
}
if (hubProxy.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
{
    await hubProxy.Invoke("MyMethod", myMethodArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the `HubConnection` class is what I wanted. I had forgotten about that class because I have a proxy service class specifically for creating a proxy to the hub and I made it only expose its `IHubProxy` property since that is what's used by the client to invoke hub methods. By exposing its `HubConnection` property as well, the client is able to check the state.

For the sake of completeness of this answer, this is what the bare bones of my client code looks like:

```
private void ConnectToHub()
{
    try
    {
        // this is a method in the proxy service class that tries to connect to the hub
        // it returns true if it was able to connect successfully
        this.connected = hubProxyService.AttempConnectionToHub();
        if (this.connected)
        {
            this.hubProxy = hubProxyService.HubProxy;
            this.hubConnection = hubProxyService.HubConnection
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        this.connected = false;
    }
}

private void MyMethodThatInvokesHubMethod()
{
    // Do some stuff
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    if (this.hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
    {
        this.ConnectToHub();
    }
    if (this.hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
    {
        await this.hubProxy.Invoke("MyHubMethod", hubMethodArgs);
    }
}
```